# Union in QGIS: missing polygon boundaries

Tags: qgis, union

I am trying to UNION two shapefiles in qgis. I use the geoprossesing tool UNION. Both sf are in the same coordinate system (same as in the project).

[image: Layer_1][image: Layer_2]

In the resulting sf some polygon borders are missing (see mock-up of desired result in last image).

[image: Union][image: Missing boundaries]

I also tried the overlay tool from Grass toolbox (or) but no result was produce! 
Any ideas or a workaround ?

Comment: Can you please post sample data? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With the tools available now by default in the "processing" toolbox (aka "sextante") the best result seems to be given by GRASS v.overlay with the option "OR". You will need to change a few colum names in your inputs, otherwise you'll get an error: GRASS adds a prefix to output column names, so when truncated they could result in identical names and that is not allowed.

If you have SAGA 2.10 it also has a union tool that gives what it seems the result you expect.

Answer (score 1):

I figured that the small polygons (lines in red in the example above) are not actually missing, the larger polygon is just displayed above the other smaller polygons. You can check by starting editing mode, select one of the large polygons and then, erase it. You will then see the underlying smaller polygons.

Comment: No, I was looking for a similar issue and happen to know this issue...

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is related to a known and unresolved high priority bug targeted for a future release, per http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8456

@Giovanni Manghi suggests SAGA 2.10 union tool, which is a good suggestion. But I think one would have to use that package as a standalone. The current SAGA version integrating with QGIS (as of 11 Apr '14) via OSGeo4 installer is 2.0.8-5, in which I find only a 'Fuzzy Union (or)' tool accessible through Processing toolbox in QGIS master.

(I am a new user and investigating how to contribute $ toward a fix for this important Union tool...)